# Createing associated record in before_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following classes in a Rails 3.1.rc4

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

What I'd like to do is create an associated team every time a user signs up using an activerecord callback. Something like this:

```
# in the User class
before_create {|user| user.create_team(name: "#{self.name}'s Team") }
```

However this doesn't seem to work properly. When I go to the `rails console` to check it, I can create a user and type `user.team` and I get a team as expected. However, if I do `user.reload` and `user.team` again, I get `nil`.

How do I get the user to properly associate with the team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out 3.1.rc4 actually has a bug which prevents `user.create_team` from working properly. See [the issue on the rails github](http://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1960). A fix has been pushed so I guess it will be fixed in the next RC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with an after save because the id is not set until the user is saved. Rails won't let this record save because the associated record, the user model, has not been saved and does not have an id.

So you should do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :team

  after_create add_team_to_user

  def add_team_to_user
      Team.create({:user => self, :name => "#{name}'s Team"})
  end

end
```

Or to prevent mass-asignment:

```
def add_team_to_user
    self.team.create({:user => self, :name => "#{name}'s Team"})
end
```

Comment: Should I be able to do it like this: `self.create_team(name: "#{name}'s team")` in order to prevent making the team model vulnerable to mass assignment? It doesn't seem to work when I try?

Comment: I'm afraid your suggestion fails because the user belongs to the team and not the other way around. When `add_team_to_user` calls `self.team.cre...`, it raises an error because `self.team == nil` since the user doesn't have a team yet. Get me? That's why I was using `user.create_team` in my code. That method doesn't seem to update the user record to represent the association properly though.

Comment: You know what, it's actually a rails bug. See this github issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1960